# How to use c:if test on the value of an option group?

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I want to test the currently selected value of a dropdown list on the same page using c:if.

```
<c:if test="${OptionGroup eq 'Month'}">
```

This doesn't work, can this be done? If so what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: What is this and how you do you get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you ask about inline checking. You can do it this way:

```
<option value='Month' ${OptionGroup=='Month'?'selected':''}>Month</option>
```